# using previous row value by looping through index conditioning

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement, dataframe

If i have dataframe with column x.
I want to make a new column x_new but I want the first row of this new column to be set to a specific number (let say -2). 
Then from 2nd row, use the previous row to iterate through the cx function

```
data = {'x':[1,2,3,4,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

def cx(x):
   if df.loc[1,'x_new']==0:
      df.loc[1,'x_new']= -2
   else:
      x_new = -10*x + 2
   return x_new

df['x_new']=(cx(df['x']))
```

The final dataframe

[image]

I am not sure on how to do this.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by just using a loop to generate your new data - might not be ideal if particularly huge but it's a quick operation. Let me know how you get on with this:

```
data = {'depth':[1,2,3,4,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

res = data['depth']
res[0] = -5.63
for i in range(1, len(res)):
    res[i] = -3 * res[i-1] + 1

df['new_depth'] = res
print(df)
```

To get

```
   depth  new_depth
0      1      -5.63
1      2      17.89
2      3     -52.67
3      4     159.01
4      5    -476.03
```

Comment: Sorry I must have mislead, i didnt mean to have all even number.
i want to be able to set first number in the new column and apply an equation (-2x+1) where x is the previous row value. Thank you

Comment: @Sharon can you update your expected dataframe with what you actually want the x_new to be?

Comment: @ Ken Syme, I have updated what i have so far with image of my expected dataframe. Thank you

Comment: @Sharon I have updated to try and answer. Also, you should really edit your question to add the extra information, rather than creating a answer.

Comment: @ Ken Syme, Thank you so much! It is what i wanted. Quick question though, If my data is already in my dataframe, i can just use res = df['depth'] but it will replace my depth column to new_depth value right?

Comment: You can use `res = df['depth'] .values` to extract a numpy array of the values. It won't replace the depth column, so will still need to assign res to a column once done (which could be depth if you want!)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have so far:

```
data = {'depth':[1,2,3,4,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df

# calculate equation
def depth_cal(d):
    z = -3*d+1 #d must be previous row
    return z

depth_cal=(depth_cal(df['depth'])) # how to set d as previous row
print (depth_cal)

depth_new =[]
for row in df['depth']:
    if row == 1:
        depth_new.append('-5.63')
    else:
        depth_new.append(depth_cal) #Does not put list in a column

    df['Depth_correct']= depth_new
```

[correct output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqzvi.png)

There is still two problem with this:
1. it does not put the depth_cal list properly in column
2. in the depth_cal function, i want d to be the previous row
Thank you